# How to prevent actor reentrancy resulting in duplicative requests?

Tags: swift, async-await, swift-concurrency

In WWDC 2021 video, [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/?time=720), they provide the following code snippet:

```swift
actor ImageDownloader {
    private var cache: [URL: Image] = [:]

    func image(from url: URL) async throws -> Image? {
        if let cached = cache[url] {
            return cached
        }

        let image = try await downloadImage(from: url)

        cache[url] = cache[url, default: image]

        return cache[url]
    }

    func downloadImage(from url: URL) async throws -> Image { ... }
}
```

The issue is that actors offer reentrancy, so `cache[url, default: image]` reference effectively ensures that even if you performed a duplicative request because of some race, that you at least check the actor’s cache after the continuation, ensuring that you get the same image for the duplicative request.

And in that video, they [say](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/?time=720):

> A better solution would be to avoid redundant downloads entirely. We’ve put that solution in the code associated with this video.

But there is no code associated with that video on the website. So, what is the better solution?

I understand the benefits of actor reentrancy (as discussed in [SE-0306](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0306-actors.md#actor-reentrancy)). E.g., if downloading four images, one does not want to prohibit reentrancy, losing concurrency of downloads. We would, effectively, like to wait for the result of a duplicative prior request for a particular image if any, and if not, start a new `downloadImage`.

Comment: Is there somewhere we can vote for the "greatest double self-answered question on StackOverflow?" I feel I should flag this question so that diamond moderators can post it as an example for others.

Comment: Look in the "Code" tab of the developer app for it

Comment: Yep, just as Rob Mayoff pointed out in his answer below, which I accepted. It was just not available on the website at the time I posted this question. It now is, though.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### UPDATE

Apple’s developer web site now includes the code snippets for WWDC videos (at least for 2021 and later). You can find the “better solution” code on the [video’s page](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/?time=719) by tapping the “Code” tab under the video player and scrolling down to “11:59 - Check your assumptions after an await: A better solution”.

### ORIGINAL

You can find the “better solution” code in [the Developer app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-developer/id640199958). Open the session in the Developer app, select the Code tab, and scroll to “11:59 - Check your assumptions after an await: A better solution”.

[image: screen shot of Developer app]

The screen shot is from my iPad, but the Developer app is also available on iPhone, Mac, and Apple TV. (I don't know if the Apple TV version gives you a way to view and copy the code, though…)

<s>As far as I can tell, the code is not available on the developer.apple.com web site, either on [the WWDC session's page](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/) or as part of a sample project.</s>

For posterity, here is Apple's code. It is extremely similar to that of Andy Ibanez:

```
actor ImageDownloader {

    private enum CacheEntry {
        case inProgress(Task<Image, Error>)
        case ready(Image)
    }

    private var cache: [URL: CacheEntry] = [:]

    func image(from url: URL) async throws -> Image? {
        if let cached = cache[url] {
            switch cached {
            case .ready(let image):
                return image
            case .inProgress(let task):
                return try await task.value
            }
        }

        let task = Task {
            try await downloadImage(from: url)
        }

        cache[url] = .inProgress(task)

        do {
            let image = try await task.value
            cache[url] = .ready(image)
            return image
        } catch {
            cache[url] = nil
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

After I came up with [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70586563/1271826), I stumbled across Andy Ibanez’s write-up, [Understanding Actors in the New Concurrency Model](https://www.andyibanez.com/posts/understanding-actors-in-the-new-concurrency-model-in-swift/), in which he does not provide Apple’s code, but provides something inspired by it. The idea is very similar, but he uses an enum to keep track of the cached and pending responses:

```swift
actor ImageDownloader {
    private enum ImageStatus {
        case downloading(_ task: Task<UIImage, Error>)
        case downloaded(_ image: UIImage)
    }
    
    private var cache: [URL: ImageStatus] = [:]
    
    func image(from url: URL) async throws -> UIImage {
        if let imageStatus = cache[url] {
            switch imageStatus {
            case .downloading(let task):
                return try await task.value
            case .downloaded(let image):
                return image
            }
        }
        
        let task = Task {
            try await downloadImage(url: url)
        }
        
        cache[url] = .downloading(task)
        
        do {
            let image = try await task.value
            cache[url] = .downloaded(image)
            return image
        } catch {
            // If an error occurs, we will evict the URL from the cache
            // and rethrow the original error.
            cache.removeValue(forKey: url)
            throw error
        }
    }
    
    private func downloadImage(url: URL) async throws -> UIImage {
        let imageRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        let (data, imageResponse) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: imageRequest)
        guard let image = UIImage(data: data), (imageResponse as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else {
            throw ImageDownloadError.badImage
        }
        return image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The key is to keep a reference to the `Task`, and if found, `await` its `value`.

Perhaps:

```swift
actor ImageDownloader {
    private var cache: [URL: Image] = [:]
    private var tasks: [URL: Task<Image, Error>] = [:]

    func image(from url: URL) async throws -> Image {
        if let image = try await tasks[url]?.value {
            print("found request")
            return image
        }

        if let cached = cache[url] {
            print("found cached")
            return cached
        }

        let task = Task {
            try await download(from: url)
        }

        tasks[url] = task
        defer { tasks[url] = nil }

        let image = try await task.value
        cache[url] = image

        return image
    }

    private func download(from url: URL) async throws -> Image {
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        guard
            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200 ..< 300 ~= response.statusCode,
            let image = Image(data: data)
        else {
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
        return image
    }
}
```