Swift actor async getter and race conditions
In Swift, when an async getter inside of an actor awaits for another function, does it allow another task to enter? For example, in the following code:
actor Foo {
    var bar: String {
        get async {
            await longOpWithSideEffect()
            return "bar"
        }
    }
}

await longOpWithSideEffect() is a suspension point and this getter is an async getter (readonly). So does swift consider it safe for multiple tasks to start reading var bar or does it wait and strictly allow only one task to access it at a time?

"In Swift, when an async getter inside of an actor awaits for another function, does it allow another task to enter?" Yes. Actors are reentrant.

Did you do any research at all? A good place to start is https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133

This is something you can easily find out by writing some code with Task.sleep and timing how long it takes for the code to run.

If you want no one else to be able to get bar while longOpWithSideEffect is running, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/70586562/5133585

Or https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0306-actors.md#actor-reentrancy

@Sweeper that is not quite what that QA is about. It's just about weeding out identical requests. Total serialization of an actor is a very hard problem, as it goes against the grain.

@matt yeah, I'm aware it's not about the general problem, but I'd imagine OP would is in a similar situation (i.e. avoiding duplicate actions) if they find this behaviour to be undesirable.

I don't think we have any basis for thinking we know the OPs use case. Or even that the OP has a use case.

Yes, I'm looking for a way to avoid duplicate actions like that one in longOpWithSideEffect. For more context, I'm implementing a token manager, the tokens are read concurrently by many different tasks but the token itself could expire, when it is expired I want to make an network call to refresh the token, hence I why I don't want another task to enter (avoid duplicates) when it's being refreshed.

To avoid being grilled alive -- I did read the description of an actor from swift.org, but it's providing misleading explanations "accessing logger.max is a possible suspension point. Because the actor allows only one task at a time to access its mutable state, if code from another task is already interacting with the logger, this code suspends while it waits to access the property." makes it sound like the equivalent of a mutex but I'm beginning to understand that it's more like a RWMutex

It seems to me that it would better to ask the question to which you really want to know the answer (i.e. about your "token manager"), and not some other question. Read and think about what an xy problem is.

An actor only allows one task to access its mutable state, but any time a suspension point is reached, the actor can be re-entered and some other task can mutate the state.
While this sounds contradictory you need to understand that "mutable state" does not refer to the object atomically, but its properties individually.
When a task is suspended it cannot be modifying a mutable property of the actor, so it is safe to allow another task to access, and potentially update, those mutable properties.
Consider a deliberately bad example actor:
actor SomeActor {

   var transactionDates: [Date] = []
   var transactionValues: [Int] = []

   func doSomething(_ value: Int) async -> Date {

      transactionDates.append(Date())
      await doSomethingWith(value)
      transactionValues.append(value)
      return transactionDates.last
   }
}

Now consider, I make two asynchronous calls to doSomething
let anActor = SomeActor()
Task {
    let transDate = await anActor.doSomething(1)
    print(transDate)
}

Task {
    let transDate = await anActor.doSomething(2)
    print(transDate)
}

At first the second task is waiting , but as soon as the await doSomethingWith(value) is reached, the first task is suspended and the second task resumes until it too reaches await doSomethingWith(value).
In theory the transactionDates and transactionValues arrays should be correlated, but it is possible that the first invocation of doSomethingWith takes longer than the second invocation, which, because of the way the code is structured (deliberately for this example), would mean that the two arrays are not correlated and that the return value of doSomething is not the transaction date of the supplied value.
The actor ensured that only one task could mutate an array property at any time, thus making the updates of the arrays thread safe, but it doesn't prevent the overall state of the actor being invalid.
Now, in this case the problem could be fixed by not splitting the array updates with an asynchronous operation.
The short answer is an actor prevents concurrent updates to individual state properties but is not a "mutex" that protects the state of the actor overall.

Great. This is helpful and clarifies my misunderstanding. Thanks!
